# 'no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const key_type&’ error' when executing code

Tags: c++, graph, maps

I'm trying to do an assignment relating to graphs in c++. Currently I get this error when I execute my code. I've been looking around for reasons behind this, but to no avail. Any help will greatly be appreciated.
My code snippet is:

```
 #include <unordered_set> 
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 map<string,string> all_vertices;
 map<string, map<string, T>> adj_list;     


template <typename T>
size_t Graph<T>::num_edges() {
int edge_num =0;
for (int i =0; i< adj_list.size();i++){      
    for (auto x : adj_list.at(i)){
              edge_num+=1;
      }
} 
return edge_num;
```

}

The error I get is:

```
 no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const key_type&’ {aka ‘const         std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’}
 546 |       at(const key_type& __k) const
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Sorry If it is really messy. I'm still very new at this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the line of code that it is referencing? It doesn't look like it is shown above.

Comment: I've updated my code now. Hopefully it shows what what is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

You declare your variable `adj_list` as type `map<string, map<string, T>>`.

That is, the map's **key** is of type `string`, but you try to access an element of this map via `adj_list.at(i)`, where `i` (the key) is of type `int` and not of type `string`.

There is no implicit conversion of `int` to `string`. That's why your compiler is complaining.

### Alternative implementation to iterate through the map(s)

```cpp
template <typename T>
size_t Graph<T>::num_edges() {
    int edge_num = 0;

    for(auto& node : adj_list) {
        for(auto& edge : node.second) {
            edge_num++;
        }
    }

    return edge_num;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? I'm not sure how to fix it to get it running.

Comment: Well, like i said. You decalred `adj_list ` as typeof `map<string, map<string, T>>` - that said, your map is not acting like a regular array (integer based index) but like an associative array (string based index). I will edit my answer and provide an alternative to iterate through the map for you.

Comment: Thank you! That helped! It makes sense. This is just so confusing at times

Comment: @SamuelWibawa You're welcome! Just let me and the others know if the solution works for you by may marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes! I've just done it. Thanks for reminding me.